# Make terminal windows always active (not on top)

Tags: command-line, r

I created a small program in R where every picture of a folder will pop up (X11) and then I have to provide an input to the terminal before showing the next one.

The problem is that every time a picture pops up, the R Graphics device windows becomes active and before I can type the input to the terminal I have to click on it, making it less efficient.

Is there a way to make the terminal windows always the active window? Or does anybody else has other sensible solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: I can have my terminal "on top" but that's not helping me. I want it to be ACTIVE all the time even when another window might pop up.

Comment: Who opens the terminal?

Comment: I run my Rscript from the terminal. Then in my script I use X11 to show a picture and that windows becomes active.

Comment: Ok, What's your desktop environment? Unity?

Comment: Yes it is Unity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a small script. Start this command in your terminal and it will never loose its focus:

<sub>ok, we have a time frame of 0.2 second **;)**</sub>

```
ID=$(xdotool getactivewindow); while true; do sleep 0.2; xdotool windowfocus $ID; done;
```

Comment: Thank you it worked!!!! I don't have reputation points and I can't upload your post :(!

Comment: Now you have =)

Comment: @A.B. Hi. I just noticed that my R script was crashing. All the windows were unresponsive. Maybe I was going trough the pictures too fast?

Comment: @JavierM88 I can not imagine. But many things are possible.